# How to fix EFI boot "Software Update is Required for this disk" when trying to boot linux?

Tags: usb, startup, efi

I created a bootable linux USB following [Ubuntu's tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview). When I startup the machine holding <kbd>Option</kbd> an EFI Boot drive shows up. When I select it, it goes to Apple Logo Loading > Then Light Grey Screen > Apple Logo Loading Again > Then the messages below show up:

[image]

With internet, I can update whatever this is, it takes 4 minutes, then the machine reboots to normal Macintosh HD. When I boot back again it keeps asking for an update. I updated 4 times and it stills shows up.

Without internet, the message below shows up:
[image]

When I click "Startup Disk" the EFI boot does not show up and all I can select is my Macintosh HD.

[image] (this image is from a forum, my Macbook is up-to-date, MacOS Catalina 10.15.4)

Googling up I found this could happen because of T2 chip securities, I disabled all of it's securities in recovery mode. The problem persists.
**What may be causing this issue? How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 3):

I am having this exact same issue following the exact same Ubuntu Tutorial. Have tried a multitude of variations with the security settings...but nothing helps and after it's downloaded something (approx 70%-ish?) the screen goes black, comes back on with Apple logo and boots into my regular Mac HD.

My supposition is the process breaks the OS and we have to follow a different path to run this software.

EDIT: To add, and an FYI, following the same Ubuntu tutorial from above, but now for a bootable DVD instead, gives the same 'error' loop.
It appears (to me at least) that any kind of external media, whether that be USB flash drives or DVDs/CDs, currently aren't supported by the Boot manager under MacOS (Catalina: version 10.15.6) despite lowering/altering the T2 chip's security settings.

EDIT 2: as Topic starter mentioned below, 2019 Macs do not support alternative OS other than Windows for now. Thanks for all your insights and let's hope someday Ubuntu will also be supported.

Comment: I think we keep this, it confirms the issue and there’s no quick fix. Knowing a process with lots of steps repeatable breaks helps people know what to do like try another plan for Ubuntu. Ideally we rescue things with a more clever answer, but let’s keep this up even if that happens.

Comment: I later found out that the MacBooks 2019 do not accept OSs but Windows 10. So installing any Linux on it breaks the system.